# Jquery slimScroll issue with another scrollbar inside

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using slimScroll plugin to make a scrollbar in my div.

```
$('#sidebar-scroll').slimScroll({
    height: '500px',
    color: '#fff',
    size: '5px',
    opacity : .35,
    wheelStep : 15,
    distance : '2px',
    railVisible: false,
    railOpacity: 1
});
```

But I also have another scrollbar without using this plugin. I use CSS to make a scrollbar. And finally, after I appplying this plugin to the outside div, scrollbar in inside div not working. Everytime I scroll, the inside div never scrolls, the outside div scrolls only. How can I solve this issue? This is my HTML and CSS. "nav-main" is the inside scroll.

```
<div id="sidebar-scroll">
  <div class="side-content">
    <ul class="nav-main">
      <li></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  ....
</div>

.nav-main {
  max-height: 171px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the inner DIV is "#inner", add this line after initialization:

```
$("#inner").on("mousewheel", function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZE8HK/42/

I faced the same problem and found this works.